# DOM manipulation not working with ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

There is too much code to past in here so please forgive me.

I have a basic application which has a single module, controller and ng-view/routProvider.

Within my controller if I perform the following, `console.log(angular.element('div').length)` the console spits out that I have 10 DIV elements. This is correct.

However when I attempt to manipulate said DOM elements via `angular.element('div').remove()` only the DOM elements outside of the ng-view get removed.

Can someone please explain what is going on? Much appreciated.

Edit:
I just noticed that if I do a remove then run angular.element('div').length, the length changes to 0 however the ng-view content remains unchanged. So my guess is the view is not being updated after I remove the elements..

Comment: you need to at least post basic code. Sounds like you should be using directive. DOM manipulation is not done from controller. Also need to show how you call `angular.element('div').remove()` , if it's before digest cycle the elements you want may not even exist. You are aware it will remove evey div in the DOM?

Comment: DOM manipulation should never be done in controllers. You should use directives to do DOM manipulation if required. Generally it's best to use the framework directives as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AngularJs, then you need to let DOM synched with your
data via AngularJs.

Here is the simplest example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'C'
  }, {
    name: 'D'
  }, ];

  $scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.items.splice(1, 2);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li>{{ item.name }}
  </ul>

  <button type="button" ng-click="remove()">remove</button>

</div>
```

Initially, there are 4 items in a Array until user hits "remove" button
 that removes 2 items from the Array.
DOM automatically gets updated according to the change of the Array.

Comment: Thank you Tosh - that is what I normally do; however if you removed the array splice function from $scope.remove and added angular.element('li').remove() would that work? Please get back to me an then I can accept your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-hide` and such DOM level manipulations are one-way binding (from js object to DOM) as angular watches js object and reflect it to html.  So, manipulating DOM directly would not propagate to js object.